# How to play my internal(mobile) video file in my android app ? give the URL path for this?

Tags: java, android

What is the uri path for play my mobile video in my android app using java?

```
videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vv);

MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.maha);

//Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

Comment: you can use something like this Uri uri= Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download"+"/t5.mkv"); where getpath method gets the path to internal storage if you dont have any external storage.

Comment: But this path is not work.